# Fetch a particular value from array object

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, traversal

I have been trying to fetch a user meta value for key ="user_listing_cat1" using ultimate member's(plugin) function `um_fetch_user()` but its not working

so I used a sql query

```
$query_results = $wpdb->get_results("
  SELECT meta_value 
  FROM wp_usermeta
  WHERE
    user_id = '". $user_id ."'
    AND meta_key ='submitted'
");
```

to fetch the data but it returns array in following format ..

```
array(1) {
  [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
    ["meta_value"]=> string(371) "a:10:{s:17:"user_listing_cat1";s:6:"Beauty";s:7:"form_id";s:5:"12097";s:9:"timestamp";s:10:"1473744616";s:7:"request";s:0:"";s:4:"role";s:6:"member";s:8:"_wpnonce";s:10:"253f5600af";s:16:"_wp_http_referer";s:18:"/add-your-listing/";s:10:"first_name";s:16:"Amritanshu Kalia";s:10:"user_email";s:22:"amritanshu@w3monks.com";s:10:"user_login";s:22:"amritanshu@w3monks.com";}"
  }
}
```

How can i get the value "Beauty" from following string

Please help me out on this

Comment: Looks like serialized data: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: It is a serialized array string.. You can get a normal array by using `unserialize($query_results[0]->meta_value)`

Comment: Thanks guys this is a life saver